# Variable Resets to 0 every refresh

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a code which lets me show how much a certain part of my website has been views.

My problem is, when I fresh refresh, it goes back to zero, instead of 2. I hope you can help me out. I want the code to run forever, or as long as I want it to, and it will just add a 1 to what it has been, even if it was yesterday. Here's the sample of the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bannerViews = 0;
function addViews (){
bannerViews = bannerViews + 1;
}

addViews();
</script>



<p>This banner has been viewed <script type="text/javascript">document.write(bannerViews);</script> times </p>
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Why must it go back to 2? You don't store the value anywhere. You should increment a server side variable for this, or use local storage.

Comment: I think  I didnt give the right statement. For example, I refresh the page once, it adds 1 to bannerViews. But when I refresh the page again, it's stuck to 1, instead getting another plus 1 which will make it two and so on.

Comment: Use localStorage if you want to store on client side or store in to DB for more accurate result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because every time you refresh your page, your code reinitializes. In-order to persist the data, you need to store it somewhere. Either in a cookie or a localstorage.

If you go ahead with the localstorage, here's how you do it.

```
var bannerViewCount = localStorage.getItem('bannerViews');

if(!bannerViewCount) {
  bannerViewCount = 0;
}

function addViews() {
  localStorage.setItem('bannerViews', ++bannerViewCount);
  document.body.innerHTML = 'Banner view count is :' + bannerViewCount;
}

addViews();
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qtb8rro5/) (click on Run on the top bar multiple times and see it incrementing)

Here, what am doing is first, fetching the banners view count. If I don't get it, I initialize it with zero.

Later, I on `addViews()` call, I increment the `bannerViewCount` by one and store it to the `localStorage`. That's it.

---

Note that the data is stored in your local storage, so if you are expecting that the count should be visible to other users too, you need to store it in a database or a text file and later parse it.

---

If you want to store it on the cloud, so that you can share the count across the visitors, you can do something like this.

```js
function addViews() {
  $.get('//jsonbin.io/b/5974382ca489d40388582791/latest', function(data) {
    var bannerViewCount = data.bannerviews;
    
    $.ajax({
      url: '//jsonbin.io/b/update/5974382ca489d40388582791',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        snippet: JSON.stringify({
          bannerviews: ++data.bannerviews
        })
      },
      success: function(fetch) {
        var data = fetch.data;
        document.body.innerHTML = 'Banner view count is : ' + JSON.parse(data).bannerviews;
      }
    });
  });
}

addViews();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Click on **"Run Code Snippet"** button and see the counter incrementing. Go to any other browser and the count will persist as expected. Note that the data stored here can be manipulated as there is no authentication in place. So avoid it if you want the count to be precise and legit.

Answer (score 0):

It goes back to 0 because the variable `bannerViews` is reinitialised to 0 on every page load.
You will need to store this variable in a JSON file/DB and fetch/update the value there.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you refresh the page the code is going to be reset and variables are included.

To solve this you have to either use a web server and have the variable saved there or find a way to save the variable to the filesystem and load it
back.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the counter is reset constantly is because you're declaring the variable during runtime. There is no persistence to the variable so every time the website is loaded, the variable starts against from 0. Each browser client would keep track of the variable separately so even if you were able to get the variable to persist on your local browser, you would not be able to keep track of the page views from other browsers. The solution to this problem is to keep track of the page views from a centralized server.

You can use a free service such as http://www.webestools.com/pages-views-counter-free-number-pages-views-statistics.html to create the counter that would persist between page views and different clients.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to get the initial value 0 , store in on the server , database or file.
change line `var bannerViews = 0;` to something like;

```
var bannerViews = getValueFromServer();
```

and every after re assigning it, you store it back to the external storage;

For now everytime you refersh the page .
the code `var bannerViews = 0;` will run and hence `bannerViews` will alwayz be re assigned to `0`